# My button can't find Google Script for Sheets. It gives me a 'could not be found' error

Tags: google-apps-script

I have managed to piece together the function below. However, now it is not allowing me to assign the script to a button. It keeps giving me this error "Script function updateData could not be found." The file name and the function name are both 'updateData'. The function works perfectly now so there should be any errors that would prevent it from finding the script.

```
function updateData() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = app.openById('1MNYUjdt0OCeOZyoNVAZbIRoM7kevG12njF5i57FyR5A');
  var db = ss.getSheetByName('Dashboard');
  var inputR  = db.getRange('B54:L54');
  var inputV = inputR.getValues();
  var data = db.getRange('B59:L1051').getValues();
    for (var i = 0; i<data.length; i++) {
    if (!data[i].join("")) break;
  }
  var emptyRow = i + 1;
  db.getRange(58 + emptyRow, 2, 1, 11).setValues(inputV);
  inputR.clearContent();
  Logger.log(emptyRow);
  Logger.log(inputV);
}
```

Update - 10/2/2021

The Problem:
I found out the problem. It is a little strange. I noticed that, if I am logged into multiple Gmail accounts within the same session of Google Chrome, when I click on tools>script editor in a spreadsheet, it will try to take me to the google script app page for the default user account(which is the first account you logged into within the session). Since I made my spreadsheet in a Gmail account other than my default it will come up with a permission error. What I did is go to the home page of the google script app and created a new project within the google script app profile page. Even though the code will work when you run it in the script app the button in google sheets will not be able to find the function to use.

Solution:
I had to open the spreadsheet in an incognito window, log into only the account I made the spreadsheet, and go to tools>script editor. In the new project, it created I pasted the code from the original script function. I updated the name of the function and assigned it to the button. BAM! Finally solved!

I noticed that my projects list in the google script app looked showed a link icon for the new project (see picture (the yellow highlight)) was a Google Sheets icon (meaning it was linked) and the old project (green highlight) has just a script icon.

[My Google Script Projects Page Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbCJw.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understanding the Root Problem:
I found out the problem. It is a little strange. I noticed that, if I am logged into multiple Gmail accounts within the same session of Google Chrome, when I click on tools>script editor in a spreadsheet, it will try to take me to the google script app page for the default user account(which is the first account you logged into within the session). Since I made my spreadsheet in a Gmail account other than my default it will come up with a permission error. What I did is go to the home page of the google script app and created a new project within the google script app profile page. Even though the code will work when you run it in the script app the button in google sheets will not be able to find the function to use.

Solution:
I had to open the spreadsheet in an incognito window, log into only the account I made the spreadsheet, and go to tools>script editor. In the new project, it created I pasted the code from the original script function. I updated the name of the function and assigned it to the button. BAM! Finally solved!

I noticed that my projects list in the google script app looked showed a link icon for the new project (see picture (the yellow highlight)) was a Google Sheets icon (meaning it was linked) and the old project (green highlight) has just a script icon.

[My Google Script Projects Page Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbCJw.png)